# PHP, Crear un nuevo ARRAY de la siguiente forma

Tags: php, array, mysqli, estructuras-de-datos

Quiero conseguir un array que tenga esta forma

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idFarm] => 2025
            [0] => 10
            [1] => 0.4
            [2] => 4789
            [3] => 0
            [4] => 0
            [5] => 12
            [6] => 0
            [7] => 23
            [8] => 0
            [9] => 0
            [10] => 75
            [11] => 18
        )

)
```

Donde solo me interesa guardar en el array una sola ves el **idFarm** y su respectivos valores, **valor** es decir, [idFarm] => 1869, [0] => 10, [1] => 20 ...

```
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
|  farm  | idFarm | valor | codigo |
+========+========+=======+========+
| MATUTE | 1869   | 10    | FR094  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| MATUTE | 1869   | 20    | FR110  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| MATUTE | 1869   | 44    | FR112  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| MATUTE | 1869   | 44    | FR126  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| MATUTE | 1869   | 12    | FR200  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| SAUL   | 1870   | 8770  | FR094  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| SAUL   | 1870   | 38    | FR110  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| SAUL   | 1870   | 90    | FR112  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| SAUL   | 1870   | 6.8   | FR126  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
| SAUL   | 1870   | 7580  | FR200  |
+--------+--------+-------+--------+
```

Este es el código con el que estoy intentando obtener el resultado, mi razonamiento es que, solo sé que paso de una granja a otra cuando el $idFarm != $fila['idFarm'], entonces agrego a mi array **granja** el idFarm e intento agregar sus valores, si el $idFarm es igual al que recibo de $fila['idFarm'], significa que sigo iterando¿? sobre los valore de la misma granja.

```
$arrayFarm = array();
$granja = array();
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) { 
    if ($idFarm !== $fila['idFarm'] ) { //Verifico si es una nueva granja para almacenar el nuevo idFarm en el array
        $granja = array("idFarm" => $fila['idFarm']);
        array_push($granja,$fila['valor']);
        $idFarm = $fila['idFarm'];

    } else if($idFarm == $fila['idFarm']) {//Si el idFarm es igual, significa que sigo iterando sobre los valores de la misma granja
        array_push($granja,$fila['valor']);
    }
}
array_push($arrayFarms,$granja);
echo '<pre>'.print_r(($arrayFarms),true).'</pre>';
```

Obtengo este resultado, es decir , por cada iteración estoy guardando el idFarm más el nuevo valor:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idFarm] => 1869
            [0] => 8790
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idFarm] => 1869
            [0] => 8790
            [1] => 40
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idFarm] => 1869
            [0] => 8790
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 90
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [idFarm] => 1869
            [0] => 8790
            [1] => 40
            [2] => 90
            [3] => 0
        )

         #   continua ...
```

¿De qué manera puedo conseguir la forma del array que necesito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Una estrategia que podrías aplicar seria la siguiente:

- Crear un arreglo donde guardar los arreglos de granjas (`eg: $farms`)
- Crear una arreglo asociativo donde guardar por cada `idFarm` la posición en el arreglo de granjas (`eg: $farmsHash`).

#### Ejemplo:

```
$farms = [];
$farmsHash = [];

while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)) { 
    if (!isset($farmsHash[$fila['idFarm']])) {// Verificamos si es una nueva granja
        $farmsHash[$fila['idFarm']] = count($farms);// Guardamos en el hash la posición que tendrá en el arreglo de granjas
        $farms[] = [$fila['idFarm']];// Agregamos la granja al arreglo de granjas y el id como dato inicial
    }
    $pos = $farmsHash[$fila['idFarm']];// Recuperamos la posición guardada en el hash
    $farms[$pos][] = $fila['valor'];// Agregamos el valor al arreglo de la granja
}

echo '<pre>' . print_r($farms, true) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías crear un primer array, recorriendo el resultado de la consulta de la siguiente forma:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [idFarm] => 1869
                [datos] => []
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [idFarm] => 1870
                [datos] => []
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [idFarm] => 1871
                [datos] => []
            )

        .....
    )
```

Posteriormente a este primer array, vuelves a recorrer el resultado de la consulta, y mientras el idFarm de este primer sea igual al idFarm de la consulta, vas agregando al campo datos con array_push.
Edito la respuesta, e incluyo una posible solución, escribiendo el código que he comentado anteriormente.

```html
$idsFarms = array();
//Primera iteración
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)){ 
    $idFarm = $fila['idFarm'];
    if (!in_array($idFarm, idsFarms)) {$idsFarms[] = $idFarm;}
}

//En $idsFarms tienes los idFarms únicos de la consulta.
$itemGranja = array();
$granja = array();
for($i=0;$i<count($idsFarms);$i++)
{
    $itemGranja['idFarm'] = $idsFarms[$i];
    $itemGranja['datos'] = array();
    $granja[] = $itemGranja;
}

/*En el array $granja tienes esto
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        ['idFarm'] => 1869,
        ['datos'] => []
    )
)*/


//Ahora recorriendo primero la consulta y el array construido
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos)){
    $idFarmOrg = $fila['idFarm'];
    $valor = $fila['valor'];
    for($i=0;$i<count($granja);$i++)
    {
        $idFarm = $granja[$i]['idFarm'];
        if ($idFarmOrg == $idFarm)
        {
            $granja[$i]['datos'][] = $valor;
        }
    }
    
}

//Aquí en el array $granja tendrías la estructura que buscas.
```

Comment: Si hay que recorrer tanto el array creado con el idFarm y el array vacío y el array que devuelve la consulta de nuevo, ¿a esto te refieres?

Answer (score 2):

Sería mas simple y manejable si usas `idFarm` como llave del primer nivel del arreglo:

```
Array( [2025] => Array( [0] => 10
                        [1] => .04 
                        [2] => 4789 ... 
                      )
     )
```

El `while` se reduce a:

```
while( $fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($datos) )
    $arrayFarm[$fila['idFarm']][] = $fila['valor'];
```

Y los valores los puedes recorrer con:

```
foreach( $arrayFarm as $idFarm => $valores )
    foreach( $valores as $valor )
        echo $idFarm.' '.$valor;
```